# Count occurrences in an array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have such documents in Mongo:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  cat: ['a', 'b, 'c', 'd', 'e']
},
{
  _id: 2,
  cat: ['f', 'g, 'h', 'i', 'j']
},
{
  _id: 3,
  cat: ['a', 'b, 'f', 'g', 'h']
},
{
  _id: 4,
  cat: ['i', 'j, 'c', 'd', 'e']
}
```

and I have to filter the documents that have at least n occurrences (let' say 3) of 'cat' in a set I have, i.e.:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']
```

So in this case only the documents with _id equal to 1 and 3 should be returned because both of them have at least 3 occurrences of the categories present in the requested array.

What is the best way to solve this problem?
Should I relay on aggregation framework or is there any easy way to do without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$redact` with `$setIntersection` for your query.

`$setIntersection` to compare the `cat` array with input array  and return array of common names documents followed by `$size` and `$redact` and compare result with 3 to keep and else remove the document.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $gte: [{
                        $size: {
                            $setIntersection: ["$cat", ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']]
                        }
                    }, 3]
                },
                then: "$$KEEP",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Comment: Really nice and clean solution!

Answer (score 3):

you can achive this using [**$setIntersection**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {$project: {cat: 1, inter: { $setIntersection: [ "$cat", ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f'] ] } } }, 
     {$project: {cat: 1, size: {$size: "$inter"}}},
     {$match: {size: {$gte: 3}}}
   ]
)
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "cat" : [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ], "size" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 3, "cat" : [ "a", "b", "f", "g", "h" ], "size" : 3 }
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/Bv-Tdl5ii7l](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bv-Tdl5ii7l)

Comment: Really nice and clean solution!